# Is it convergent ???

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Hello can I get any help in this question and what is the difference between the two spaces.

Show that if the following sequence is convergent in the two spaces 
$
{C}\left[{0,1}\right]$ and $\hspace{0.33em}{C}^{1}\left[{0,1}\right]
$
:

$
{x}_{n}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}\frac{{t}^{{n}\mathrm{{+}}{1}}}{{n}\mathrm{{+}}{1}}\mathrm{{-}}\frac{{t}^{{n}\mathrm{{+}}{2}}}{{n}\mathrm{{+}}{2}}{\mathrm{,}}{n}\mathrm{{=}}{1}{\mathrm{,}}{2}{\mathrm{,..}}
$

Comment: I don't know really I didn't get it

Comment: You should specify which norms are assumed for the two spaces. It should not be hard to see that $x_n(t) \to 0$ pointwise, and $x'_n(t) \to 0$ pointwise.

Comment: Why do we take the derivative ??

Comment: @user416990 that depends on the norm of each space...